# correlation plots for consecutive study sites within a loop: how can i add site names as main headers?

Tags: r, loops, plot

edited to include `dput(Nitrate_set)` output:

```
structure(list(SITE.NO = structure(c(41L, 42L, 41L, 3L, 35L, 
42L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 1L, 40L, 1L, 40L, 40L, 16L, 40L, 42L, 40L, 
40L, 42L, 1L, 42L, 40L, 1L, 40L, 1L, 40L, 4L, 42L, 21L, 15L, 
5L, 36L, 40L, 40L, 2L, 41L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 42L, 19L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 42L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 39L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 39L, 11L, 37L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 32L, 1L, 41L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 40L, 42L, 1L, 2L, 38L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 41L, 38L, 
1L, 8L, 42L, 42L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 33L, 1L, 2L, 18L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 41L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 40L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 41L, 10L, 14L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 42L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 38L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 38L, 42L, 38L, 40L, 42L, 41L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 38L, 38L, 1L, 38L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 17L, 2L, 42L, 41L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 38L, 
1L, 1L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 26L, 38L, 38L, 1L, 2L, 
38L, 38L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 38L, 38L, 1L, 31L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
34L, 24L, 38L, 2L, 28L, 38L, 25L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 1L, 
38L, 1L, 29L, 38L, 38L, 1L, 38L, 2L, 2L, 22L, 1L, 27L, 1L, 30L, 
38L, 38L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 38L, 2L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 13L, 38L, 1L, 38L, 
1L, 23L, 2L, 39L, 20L, 38L, 38L, 2L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 
38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 1L, 38L, 38L, 41L, 38L, 1L, 38L, 38L, 2L, 
38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 1L, 38L, 1L, 38L, 2L, 2L, 38L, 1L, 40L, 2L, 
42L, 41L, 42L, 38L, 42L, 38L, 41L, 2L, 42L, 1L, 38L, 38L, 42L, 
2L, 42L, 38L, 38L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 39L, 40L, 2L, 42L, 1L, 1L, 38L, 
40L, 41L, 2L, 41L, 41L, 1L, 2L, 41L, 1L, 39L, 41L, 1L, 41L, 40L, 
1L, 39L, 39L, 2L, 40L, 38L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 38L, 39L, 1L, 2L, 38L, 
41L, 38L, 38L, 2L, 38L, 38L, 41L, 2L, 39L, 43L, 39L, 41L, 43L, 
43L, 43L, 43L, 41L, 39L, 39L, 41L, 43L, 41L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 
39L, 39L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 41L), .Label = c("1110056", 
"1111019", "1120054", "1120055", "1120060", "1120061", "1120062", 
"1120065", "1120066", "1120067", "1120068", "1120069", "1120070", 
"1120071", "1120073", "1120074", "1120075", "1120076", "1120077", 
"1120078", "1120079", "1120080", "1120081", "1120082", "1120083", 
"1120084", "1120085", "1120086", "1120087", "1120088", "1120089", 
"1120090", "1120091", "1120092", "1120094", "1120095", "1120096", 
"113006A", "122013A", "125013A", "126001A", "1260122", "141010A"
), class = "factor"), SITE.NAME = structure(c(8L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 
2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 
8L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 
7L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 
7L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 
8L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 
3L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 5L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 9L, 
7L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 9L, 3L, 
3L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 9L, 7L, 2L, 
9L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 9L, 7L, 
7L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
2L, 9L, 3L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 3L, 9L, 3L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 9L, 
5L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
6L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 
6L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 9L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 
3L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L), .Label = c("Coochin Creek at Mawsons Road", 
"Johnstone River at Coquette Point Gbr_Jri_Wq", "Mulgrave River at Deeral", 
"Pioneer River at Dumbleton Weir Headwater", "Plane Creek at Sucrogen Weir", 
"Proserpine River at Glen Isla", "Russell River at East Russell", 
"Sandy Creek at Homebush", "Tully River at Euramo"), class = "factor"), 
    Date = structure(c(64L, 62L, 48L, 63L, 42L, 8L, 54L, 75L, 
    75L, 48L, 12L, 73L, 3L, 37L, 40L, 17L, 69L, 69L, 47L, 4L, 
    27L, 4L, 48L, 64L, 74L, 79L, 74L, 79L, 54L, 49L, 40L, 80L, 
    61L, 62L, 64L, 53L, 3L, 80L, 53L, 4L, 81L, 45L, 53L, 53L, 
    50L, 53L, 50L, 31L, 50L, 50L, 81L, 53L, 17L, 53L, 50L, 70L, 
    46L, 43L, 4L, 6L, 70L, 53L, 13L, 65L, 13L, 2L, 56L, 37L, 
    25L, 53L, 65L, 68L, 56L, 46L, 2L, 70L, 13L, 12L, 81L, 40L, 
    6L, 24L, 16L, 16L, 46L, 68L, 2L, 80L, 52L, 68L, 81L, 81L, 
    14L, 46L, 30L, 60L, 30L, 70L, 56L, 45L, 61L, 16L, 65L, 56L, 
    16L, 81L, 55L, 5L, 32L, 10L, 13L, 13L, 46L, 72L, 32L, 49L, 
    14L, 4L, 8L, 42L, 35L, 1L, 41L, 37L, 81L, 63L, 52L, 76L, 
    1L, 32L, 53L, 40L, 55L, 52L, 58L, 53L, 10L, 53L, 20L, 48L, 
    80L, 19L, 49L, 13L, 56L, 53L, 19L, 50L, 21L, 46L, 35L, 21L, 
    19L, 45L, 16L, 64L, 81L, 19L, 32L, 25L, 52L, 72L, 38L, 49L, 
    49L, 26L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 32L, 80L, 16L, 56L, 46L, 50L, 1L, 
    32L, 41L, 41L, 32L, 58L, 58L, 41L, 56L, 13L, 23L, 68L, 55L, 
    49L, 32L, 15L, 5L, 55L, 2L, 40L, 65L, 65L, 53L, 58L, 25L, 
    13L, 5L, 37L, 61L, 11L, 35L, 65L, 60L, 11L, 1L, 52L, 45L, 
    58L, 52L, 6L, 56L, 49L, 68L, 13L, 68L, 35L, 49L, 55L, 49L, 
    45L, 30L, 55L, 19L, 8L, 67L, 22L, 70L, 5L, 52L, 45L, 34L, 
    49L, 45L, 32L, 80L, 16L, 13L, 70L, 49L, 67L, 16L, 19L, 44L, 
    67L, 42L, 21L, 21L, 80L, 1L, 45L, 45L, 59L, 4L, 59L, 29L, 
    29L, 21L, 45L, 71L, 45L, 45L, 80L, 4L, 40L, 40L, 8L, 4L, 
    15L, 81L, 18L, 18L, 15L, 20L, 54L, 81L, 12L, 76L, 57L, 18L, 
    12L, 81L, 20L, 80L, 80L, 15L, 81L, 81L, 31L, 20L, 8L, 28L, 
    18L, 20L, 18L, 20L, 80L, 4L, 47L, 69L, 18L, 18L, 62L, 18L, 
    20L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 18L, 28L, 9L, 8L, 18L, 
    18L, 9L, 12L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 28L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 8L, 
    66L, 39L, 8L, 20L, 77L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 20L, 4L, 74L, 12L, 
    51L, 20L, 4L, 78L, 78L, 81L, 81L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 33L, 
    12L), .Label = c("1/01/2019", "1/02/2019", "1/11/2018", "10/12/2018", 
    "11/02/2019", "11/03/2019", "11/04/2019", "11/12/2018", "12/12/2018", 
    "13/12/2018", "14/01/2019", "14/12/2018", "15/01/2019", "15/11/2018", 
    "15/12/2018", "16/01/2019", "16/11/2018", "16/12/2018", "17/01/2019", 
    "17/12/2018", "18/01/2019", "18/02/2019", "18/03/2019", "18/09/2018", 
    "19/01/2019", "19/02/2019", "19/11/2018", "19/12/2018", "2/01/2019", 
    "2/02/2019", "2/11/2018", "20/01/2019", "20/04/2019", "20/12/2018", 
    "21/01/2019", "21/04/2019", "22/11/2018", "24/01/2019", "24/04/2019", 
    "24/12/2018", "25/01/2019", "25/02/2019", "25/09/2018", "25/10/2018", 
    "25/12/2018", "26/01/2019", "26/09/2018", "26/11/2018", "26/12/2018", 
    "27/01/2019", "27/03/2019", "27/12/2018", "28/01/2019", "28/08/2018", 
    "28/12/2018", "29/01/2019", "29/11/2018", "29/12/2018", "3/01/2019", 
    "3/02/2019", "3/03/2019", "3/07/2018", "3/09/2018", "3/12/2018", 
    "30/01/2019", "30/11/2018", "30/12/2018", "31/01/2019", "31/07/2018", 
    "31/12/2018", "4/01/2019", "4/02/2019", "5/11/2018", "5/12/2018", 
    "6/12/2018", "7/01/2019", "7/03/2019", "7/12/2018", "8/10/2018", 
    "8/12/2018", "9/12/2018"), class = "factor"), Trios.nitrate..mg.L. = c(0.01, 
    0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 
    0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 
    0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.06, 0.06, 
    0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.09, 
    0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
    0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 
    0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 
    0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 
    0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 
    0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 
    0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 
    0.14, 0.14, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 
    0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 
    0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.17, 
    0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 
    0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.19, 0.19, 
    0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 
    0.19, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
    0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 
    0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 
    0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 
    0.22, 0.22, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 
    0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 
    0.23, 0.23, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 
    0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 
    0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.27, 
    0.27, 0.27, 0.28, 0.28, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 
    0.31, 0.31, 0.32, 0.32, 0.33, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.35, 0.35, 
    0.36, 0.36, 0.37, 0.37, 0.37, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 
    0.39, 0.39, 0.4, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.43, 0.44, 0.48, 0.49, 
    0.49, 0.51, 0.51, 0.53, 0.56, 0.57, 0.58, 0.58, 0.58, 0.58, 
    0.58, 0.61, 0.64, 0.73, 0.76, 0.76, 0.81, 0.82, 0.85, 0.85, 
    0.85, 0.86, 0.88, 0.92, 0.94, 0.96, 1, 1.04, 1.04, 1.06, 
    1.14, 1.18, 1.34, 1.37, 1.45, 1.48, 1.48, 1.48, 1.54, 1.58, 
    1.73, 1.76, 1.82, 1.85, 1.95, 1.95, 1.96, 2.15, 2.18, 2.26, 
    2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.69, 3.12), Chem.centre.Nox..mg.L. = c(5e-04, 
    0.001, 0.086, 0.048, 0.036, 0.015, 0.001, 0.088, 0.305, 0.012, 
    0.078, 0.023, 0.047, 0.002, 0.08, 0.004, 0.002, 0.003, 0.002, 
    0.029, 0.009, 0.045, 0.062, 0.006, 0.149, 0.087, 0.311, 0.008, 
    5e-04, 0.152, 0.03, 0.339, 0.103, 0.048, 0.003, 0.039, 0.159, 
    0.156, 0.043, 0.209, 0.091, 0.135, 0.039, 0.042, 0.041, 0.049, 
    0.045, 0.021, 0.045, 0.044, 0.235, 0.051, 0.03, 0.063, 0.046, 
    0.075, 0.058, 0.303, 0.227, 0.092, 0.094, 0.066, 0.068, 0.055, 
    0.073, 0.186, 0.079, 5e-04, 0.073, 0.086, 0.074, 0.097, 0.083, 
    0.062, 0.086, 0.084, 0.088, 0.098, 0.033, 0.093, 0.122, 0.104, 
    0.09, 0.093, 0.078, 0.095, 0.086, 0.178, 0.155, 0.098, 0.123, 
    0.134, 0.005, 0.065, 0.105, 0.109, 0.175, 0.098, 0.093, 0.081, 
    0.116, 0.116, 0.097, 0.098, 0.114, 0.159, 0.083, 0.126, 0.119, 
    0.092, 0.104, 0.116, 0.093, 0.114, 0.12, 0.118, 5e-04, 0.185, 
    0.265, 0.14, 0.168, 0.133, 0.116, 0.006, 0.057, 0.149, 0.086, 
    0.143, 0.137, 0.134, 0.164, 0.237, 0.114, 0.106, 0.123, 0.121, 
    0.086, 0.117, 0.184, 5e-04, 0.198, 0.148, 0.103, 0.159, 0.128, 
    0.134, 0.156, 0.134, 0.172, 0.082, 0.168, 0.176, 0.168, 0.153, 
    0.167, 0.001, 0.162, 0.171, 0.165, 0.152, 0.156, 0.17, 0.126, 
    0.124, 0.105, 0.188, 0.159, 0.17, 0.147, 0.174, 0.099, 0.176, 
    0.15, 0.141, 0.213, 0.166, 0.173, 0.181, 0.188, 0.192, 0.156, 
    0.062, 0.157, 0.167, 0.149, 0.234, 0.13, 0.172, 0.154, 0.194, 
    0.389, 0.171, 0.163, 0.181, 0.2, 0.156, 0.186, 0.17, 0.19, 
    0.196, 0.156, 0.218, 0.298, 0.218, 0.184, 0.206, 0.154, 0.193, 
    0.18, 0.192, 0.192, 0.145, 0.196, 0.158, 0.23, 0.172, 0.171, 
    0.154, 0.162, 0.209, 0.215, 0.179, 0.196, 0.183, 0.161, 0.208, 
    0.194, 0.208, 0.22, 0.178, 0.274, 0.184, 0.214, 0.222, 0.144, 
    0.169, 0.168, 0.183, 0.223, 0.184, 0.195, 0.181, 0.2, 0.202, 
    0.218, 0.191, 0.223, 0.057, 0.206, 0.237, 0.231, 0.244, 0.295, 
    0.217, 0.153, 0.214, 0.256, 0.17, 0.246, 0.25, 0.232, 0.247, 
    0.168, 0.247, 0.156, 0.214, 0.196, 0.183, 0.24, 0.205, 0.519, 
    0.197, 0.119, 0.306, 0.143, 0.257, 0.118, 0.269, 0.352, 0.256, 
    0.13, 0.307, 0.066, 0.272, 0.19, 0.261, 0.172, 0.222, 0.232, 
    0.236, 0.29, 0.276, 0.316, 0.217, 0.257, 0.206, 0.247, 0.28, 
    0.322, 0.304, 0.412, 0.36, 0.377, 0.421, 0.326, 0.33, 0.464, 
    0.331, 0.212, 0.456, 0.434, 0.486, 0.253, 0.48, 0.337, 0.549, 
    0.45, 0.611, 0.579, 0.594, 0.613, 0.672, 0.663, 0.389, 0.694, 
    0.718, 0.71, 0.692, 0.754, 0.816, 0.77, 0.863, 0.878, 0.388, 
    0.914, 0.42, 0.918, 1.06, 0.859, 1.58, 1.39, 0.922, 0.633, 
    1.22, 1.31, 0.399, 1.46, 1.71, 1.51, 1.58, 0.271, 0.44, 4.24, 
    3.65, 2.06, 2.61, 5e-04, 0.001, 0.065, 1.38, 2.91)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-361L))
>
```

The input file (Nitrate_set) includes 9 study sites. I have been able to produce a correlation plot between two variables of interest consecutively for each site within a loop, but am unable to add to appropriate site name as a header for each plot. Here's an example of the data:

```
                                     SITE.NAME        COR
1                Coochin Creek at Mawsons Road -0.1122249
2 Johnstone River at Coquette Point Gbr_Jri_Wq  0.3614868
3                     Mulgrave River at Deeral  0.9338604
4    Pioneer River at Dumbleton Weir Headwater  0.7270477
5                 Plane Creek at Sucrogen Weir  0.8337472
6                Proserpine River at Glen Isla  0.6695578
7                Russell River at East Russell  0.9879924
8                      Sandy Creek at Homebush  0.9756037
9                        Tully River at Euramo  0.9751152
```

I would like each correlation plot to display a header appropriate to it's site name. I'm not sure where to put that code within the loop.

This is the first time I am trying to produce plots within a loop and I'm a novice coder. I don't know what to try next..

```
#Creating function func to calculate correlation for single site   
func <- function(Nitrate_set){  return(data.frame(COR = cor(Nitrate_set$Trios.nitrate..mg.L., Nitrate_set$Chem.centre.Nox..mg.L.))) }

#Calling func Function for each site name and storing the results in cor_result. cor_result will show correlation for each site as a list.
cor_result <- ddply(Nitrate_set, .(SITE.NAME), func)
cor_result

#Creating function to display correlation plot for every site
funcPlot <- function(Nitrate_set){  
  chart.Correlation(Nitrate_set[,c(4,5)], histogram=TRUE, pch=19)
}

#Calling the function to display the plots. This will return nine plots serially. At this point we need to title site name for each site.
ddply(Nitrate_set, .(SITE.NAME), funcPlot)
```

I expect each plot to be displayed with a header but am unable to work out how and where to put that section of code within the loop

Comment: Can you paste here the output of `dput(Nitrate_set)` so we can try it.

Comment: I've not used dput before. there's a huge output. I'll paste here but please let me know if ive done it incorrectly. thanks for your help!

Comment: Well you could also just post a few rows of the data. But now we've got something to work with.